# Design and Coding best practice [codenameone]

Tags: codenameone

New to codenameone . Please share generic design and coding best practice to make a robust , reusable framework , so that it can be used and reduce some effort for future app development.

Answer (score 0):

Codename One already is a framework for reducing the effort and increasing reuse for future projects. There isn't much you need to build on top of it to further increase abstraction.